# Composite Key and objects composition code first

Tags: .net, ef-code-first

I am very new to code first. I have tried reading as much as I can but I have not found an answer to my question. When using object composition and code first how do you create a composite key. for example

```
    public class Foo
    {
     public FooID {get; set;}
     public FooName {get; set;}
    }
    public class Bar
    {
    public virutal Foo {get; set;}
    public BarID {get; set;}
    public BarName {get; set;}
    }
```

*How can I make sure in the DB schema that FooID and BarID are composite keys?*

*Also should I even do the virtual Foo?* *or should create bar like this?* *If I use the below bar implementation is there a way of being able to use statements like this **`bar.foo.name`** (i doubt it but maybe EF does some cool magic to let this happen)?*

```
Public Class Bar
{
public FooID {get; set;}
public BarID  {get; set;}
public BarName {get; set;}
}
```

IF possible I would like to be able to do all that through data annotations. Thank you very much

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436731/composite-key-as-foreign-key

answer to my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[composite key as foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436731/composite-key-as-foreign-key)

Answered the question. Posting this as a answer to be more visible to other people needing this information.