# how to set NAME for "multi fields" primary keys (Constraint Primary Key) in entity framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

How to set name for "multi fields" primary keys (Constraint Primary Key) in entity framework??
for example :

```
// CONSTRAINT PKRoles PRIMARY KEY (Rolename, ApplicationName)
```

i can implement only part of the code :

sql cod:

```
CREATE TABLE Roles
(
    Rolename Text (255) NOT NULL,
    ApplicationName Text (255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PKRoles PRIMARY KEY (Rolename, ApplicationName)
)
```

implement (convert for entity):

```
public class Roles
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public string Rolename { get; set; } //(255) NOT NULL

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; } //(255) NOT NULL

    //CONSTRAINT PKRoles PRIMARY KEY (Rolename, ApplicationName)
}
```

**i see in keys section of database , that create key with "*PK_dbo.Roles*" name !
but i need create key "*PKRoles* " neme!**

please help me to implement end line above code.
thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: in this time and date i do 3 days researching for found answer my question , but i not found accepted answer.  
entity framework is very good and also is professional framwork but Not yet complete.  
but according to i knowing Microsoft's, I sure it will be complete framework.

Answer (score 0):

Does the code below do what you want?

```
public class Roles
{
    [Key, Column("PKRoles", Order = 0)]
    public string Rolename { get; set; } //(255) NOT NULL

    [Key, Column("PKRoles", Order = 1)]
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; } //(255) NOT NULL
}
```

The word you are looking for is "composite key" and you might be able to use the fluent API. That might help your search if this does not work.

Comment: thanks my friend ,  
your code call error:
"{"One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:\r\n\r\nPKRoles: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'PKRoles' is already defined.\r\nRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'Roles' is based on type 'Roles' that has no keys defined.\r\n"}"
i previously tried this .
thanks again.

Comment: Thank you, but no, unfortunately.