# EntityFramework - Composite Key Table with FK to another Composite Key Table

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, foreign-key-relationship, composite-primary-key

I've **two tables** both with **composite primary keys**. **Both** have in common **one of the primary key's with a foreign key** to another table.

The problem is that when i create the migrations, it messes up the foreign keys.

**I must use data annotations.**

Example:

```
public class City
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string CityCode { get; set; } 

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public string CompanyCode { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }     

    [ForeignKey("CompanyCode")]
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}

public class PostCode
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string Code { get; set; } 

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public string CompanyCode { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; } 

    public string CityCode { get; set; }      

    [ForeignKey("CompanyCode")]
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CityCode, CompanyCode")]
    public virtual City City { get; set; }
}
```

- *PostCode* and *City* have a composite primary key (Code, **CompanyCode**).
- *PostCode* has a foreign key to the table *City* (**CityCode**, **CompanyCode**).

The problem is that the *CompanyCode* is **part of the primary key and at the same time is part of the composite foreign key** to *City*.

When i say that it messes up the foreign keys i mean the following:

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.PostCodes_dbo.Companies_CompanyCode] FOREIGN KEY ([CompanyCode]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Companies] ([CompanyCode]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.PostCodes_dbo.Cities_CompanyCode_CityCode] FOREIGN KEY ([CompanyCode], [CityCode]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Cities] ([CityCode], [CompanyCode])
```

In the second constraint, it references *CompanyCode* with *CityCode* and *CityCode* with *CompanyCode*.

I can't find any example in the internet with any scenario like this.

Where am i wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1**

Between *City* and *Company* there is a simples primar key *CompanyCode*.
The same for *PostCodes* and *Company*.

Comment: Can you share briefly more about your logic? What kind of relationship exist between `City` and  `Company`?

Comment: @octavioccl ok, wrote it in Edit 1, see the post again please.

Answer (score 1):

If between `City` and `Company` you want to create a one-to-one relationship I'm afraid that is not possible following your model. When you are configuring a one-to-one relationship, Entity Framework requires that the primary key of the dependent end also be the foreign key, otherwise EF doesn't see it as one-to-one relationship. The dependend end in your case es `City`, but you have a problem, you want to add another PK, that is `CityCode`, that breaks what it means a one to one relationship because, for example, the below records could happen:

```
Company             City 
Id            CityCode CompanyId
1               ee33a      1
2               aa23b      1
```

That's way, if you want to achieve your escenario, I guess that you have to create a one-to-many relationship between `Company` and `City`. Using Data Annotations could be this way:

```
public class City
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string CityCode { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("Company"),Column(Order = 2)]
    public string CompanyCode { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

You can omit the `Cities` navigation property in `Company` if you don't want have reference to the cities related to a `Company`.

The same applies to the `PostCode` Entity.

### Update:

To achieve what you want in the `PostCode` entity, you have to map the FKs this way:

```
public class PostCode
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Key,ForeignKey("City"), Column(Order = 2)]
    public string CityCompanyCode { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("City"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public string CityCode { get; set; }


    public virtual City City { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Company")]
    public string CompanyCode { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436731/composite-key-as-foreign-key) is a good example of how you should treat the composite FKs

Comment: Thank you for your time. But the problem is located between Cities and PostCodes, because i can't specify which primary key from "City" match the the foreign key from "PostCode". I can simulate all this in SQL and get it to work, the problem is that entity framework messes up the foreign keys from "PostCode". If you look closely to the SQL part i posted, you will see that the foreign key [dbo.PostCodes].CityCode matchs the [dbo.Cities].CompanyCode instead [dbo.Cities].CityCode.

Comment: Hello Leandro, I have updated my answer. You can't map two FKs (although they represent the same field) in one property. You have to separate them. Hope this help you

Comment: But i can map two FK's (to a composite primary key table) normally, this problem only occurs when i'm trying to do it from another composite primary key table

Comment: I know, the FK mapping that  was wrong was this:`[ForeignKey("CityCode, CompanyCode")]`. In the ForeignKey Attribute only one property is specified. Did you try the variant that I proposed you in the update?

Comment: Yes, it works but the objective was to use only one company column

Comment: But that is not possible if you are creating two different relationships

Comment: It is possible, i can reproduce with SQL. But entity framework just messes up the Keys

Answer (score 0):

I always add a primary key to my tables, por example: CityId int, PostCode int. with this i resolve relations.

```
public class PostCode
{   
[Key, Column(Order = 0)]
public string PostCodeId  { get; set; } 

[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public string Code { get; set; } 

public string CompanyCode { get; set; }

public string Description { get; set; } 

public string CityCode { get; set; }      

[ForeignKey("CompanyCode")]
public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("CityCode, CompanyCode")]
public virtual City City { get; set; }
}
```

thanks

Comment: yes, i agree that it would be easier, but right now it's not an option... Thanks