# EF6 FKs are not correctly set for non-identity PKs

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-6

I stumbled on a problem after a migration from EF4.1 to EF6.

To simplify I created the example below.
The problem is that on the call `ctx.SaveChanges();` `p.CityId` gets populated with the correct value, but not `p.CityId2`.

If after the creation of the City entity I call the `ctx.SaveChanges()` the `p.CityId2` is set correctly.

On EF4.1 the code below sets the `p.CityId2`correctly without the intermediate `ctx.SaveChanges()`.

Any idea why this happens and what I should do in this case except the intermediate `ctx.SaveChanges()`. Why does EF correctly propagates the CityId but not the CityId2 ?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (MyContext ctx = new MyContext())
        {
            City c = new City() { Id2 = 32767 };
            ctx.Set<City>().AddOrUpdate(c);

            Person p = new Person() { Id2 = 32767 };
            p.City = c;
            ctx.Set<Person>().AddOrUpdate(p);

            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

class City
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Id2 { get; set; }
}

class Person
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Id2 { get; set; }

    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public int CityId2 { get; set; }
    public City City { get; set; }
}

internal sealed class CityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<City>
{
    public CityConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(t => new { t.Id, t.Id2 });
    }
}

internal sealed class PersonConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Person>
{
    public PersonConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(t => new { t.Id, t.Id2 });
    }
}

class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyContext>());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CityConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PersonConfiguration());
    }
}
```

Comment: Huh? Why would you use a composite primary key where one of its components is an identity column? An identity column is already unique by itself.

Comment: the database is replicated. the second id is an sql instance id.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this thread

> [composite key as foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436731/composite-key-as-foreign-key)
>   ?

Maybe you're missing something like following in Person configuration?

```
.HasForeignKey(p => new {p.CityId, p.CityId2});
```

Comment: hi, yes. but EF is smart enough to know that the 2 ids are a composite FK.  I did implicitly declare the FK but that does not help. `HasRequired(t => t.City).WithMany().HasForeignKey(fk => new { fk.CityId, fk.CityId2 });`