# EF Core 3.1 with composite primary key navigation property

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, composite-primary-key

My Tables

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SeqA START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
CREATE TABLE TblA (
    CompanyID BIGINT NOT NULL,
    ID BIGINT DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR SeqA),
    ..
    PRIMARY KEY (CompanyID, ID));
```

And

```
CREATE TABLE TblB (
    MyID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    ..
    CompanyID BIGINT NOT NULL, -- These are foreign key references to TblA
    ID BIGINT NOT NULL
);
```

**Question 1:** How can I setup foreign key to reference TblA from TblB?

**Question 2:** When using EF Core 3.1, how can I setup **navigation property** for CompanyID and ID in TblB to references TblA?

Comment: What's the point of having a composite key? `ID` alone is unique. Adding `CompanyID` dooesn't help at all. Quite the oppositte - it allows inserting *duplicate* ID values by specifying a different `CompanyID`. This would make sense in a many-to-many table. Is this what `tblA` is?

Comment: I have the same application deployed in different PCs supporting different companies. At the end of the day, the data need to be merged.

Comment: You can specify an anonymous type combining multiple properties both in `HasKey` and  `HasForeignKey`.  Check [Composite Key as Foreing Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436731/composite-key-as-foreign-key).

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try.