# Entity Framework composite primary key and foreign key

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-6, foreign-keys

I'm migrating a piece of software made in .NET Framework 4.7.2. I have an SQL Server database. For the creation of entities I added an ADO.net object using code first from database.

The entities were created, but when I execute the code it returns the following error

> MEG_OFERTAS_MEG_OPERACIONES: : The types of all properties in the
> Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the
> corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of
> property 'DT_DIA_OPERACION' on entity 'MEG_OPERACIONES' does not match
> the type of property 'I_NRO_OFERTA' on entity 'MEG_OFERTAS' in the
> referential constraint 'MEG_OFERTAS_MEG_OPERACIONES'.

My entities are the following

```
public partial class MEG_OFERTAS : IEntity
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public MEG_OFERTAS()
    {
        MEG_OPERACIONES = new HashSet<MEG_OPERACIONES>();
        MEG_OPERACIONES1 = new HashSet<MEG_OPERACIONES>();
    }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0, TypeName = "numeric")]
    public decimal I_NRO_OFERTA { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1, TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime DT_DIA_OPERACION { get; set; }

    .
    .
    .
    .

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<MEG_OPERACIONES> MEG_OPERACIONES { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<MEG_OPERACIONES> MEG_OPERACIONES1 { get; set; }
}
```

and the other one is

```
public partial class MEG_OPERACIONES : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0, TypeName = "numeric")]
    public decimal I_NRO_OPERACION { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1, TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime DT_DIA_OPERACION { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
    public decimal I_NRO_OFERTA_COMPRA { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
    public decimal I_NRO_OFERTA_VENTA { get; set; }
    .
    .
    .
    public virtual MEG_OFERTAS MEG_OFERTAS { get; set; }

    public virtual MEG_OFERTAS MEG_OFERTAS1 { get; set; }
}
```

And in de dbcontext I have the next piece of code

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MEG_OFERTAS>()
    .HasMany(e => e.MEG_OPERACIONES)
    .WithRequired(e => e.MEG_OFERTAS)
    .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.I_NRO_OFERTA_COMPRA, e.DT_DIA_OPERACION })
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<MEG_OFERTAS>()
    .HasMany(e => e.MEG_OPERACIONES1)
    .WithRequired(e => e.MEG_OFERTAS1)
    .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.I_NRO_OFERTA_VENTA, e.DT_DIA_OPERACION })
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

[The ER Diagram for one of the relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2uge.png)

[And the other relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R12km.png)

Can anyone help me to solve my problem please?

Comment: Check out this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/5441569/3334470. It should help identify mistakes.

Comment: I already tried the examples on that post... As you can see I have the fluent API part in my code, but it doesn't solve my problem... I can't see what I am doing wrong